# AggregateByKey Function with key-value pairs in Pyspark

Tags: pyspark, aggregate-functions

I have a question regarding aggregatebykey in pyspark.

I have an RDD dataset as follows:
premierRDD=[('Chelsea', ('2016–2017', 93)), ('Chelsea', ('2015–2016', 50))]

I wish to sum up the scores of 50 & 93 using the aggegrateByKey function, and my expected output should be:
[('Chelsea', '2016–2017', (93,143)), ('Chelsea', '2015–2016', (50,143))]

```
seqFunc = (lambda x, y: ('', x[0] + y[1]))
combFunc = (lambda x, y: (x[0] + y[0], x[1] + y[1]))

premierAgg = premierMap.aggregateByKey((0,0), seqFunc, combFunc)
```

However, I get this output instead:
[('Chelsea', ('', 143))]

Can someone advise me how to use the aggregrateByKey function appropriately?

Comment: The problem is: if you aggregate by key, same keys are combined and in the functions you specify how the combination works. This means your result will only contain `"chelsea"` once

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I adjusted your code to achieve the desired result. First you need to maintain the "year" value in the seqFunc. Therefore I added `y[0]` there. Then the combination has to be changed to not only contain the sum, but also the original value in a tuple. Furthermore the year value remains as well. This would result in `[('Chelsea', [(u'2016-2017', (93, 143)), (u'2015-2016', (50, 143))])]`, as I explained in the comment same keys will be combined. To achieve your output with 2 times chelsea you can just use an additional map function as described.

```python
rdd = sc.parallelize([('Chelsea', (u"2016-2017", 93)), ('Chelsea', (u"2015-2016", 50))])
seqFunc = (lambda x, y: (y[0], x[0] + y[1]))
combFunc = (lambda x, y: [(x[0], (x[1],x[1] + y[1])),(y[0],(y[1],x[1]+y[1]))])

premierAgg = rdd.aggregateByKey((0,0), seqFunc,combFunc)
print premierAgg.map(lambda r: [(r[0], a) for a in r[1]]).collect()[0]
```

Output:

```python
[('Chelsea', (u'2016-2017', (93, 143))), ('Chelsea', (u'2015-2016', (50, 143)))]
```